# Dragging doesn't trigger SwipeRefreshLayout refresh action

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

What I'm trying to do: just a simple event where if you drag down the fragment, you would trigger the method that fetches data from firestore, and populate the recyclerview.

Problem: Dragging doesn't display the refresh icon, or trigger the fetch method, *prepareData()*.

The following is the layout file of the fragment.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/operate_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="145dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_activities_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="35dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Fragment, *ActivitiesFragment.java*

```
public class ActivitiesFragment extends BaseFragment {
private static final String TAG = "ActivitiesFragment";
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private FloatingActionButton fabActivitiesAdd;
private ActivitiesAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<ActivityModel> activities = new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private Query activitiesQuery;

public ActivitiesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming_activites, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable 
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    fabActivitiesAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_activities_add);
    mRecyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.operate_rv);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    mAdapter = new ActivitiesAdapter(activities, getContext());
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this::prepareData);

    prepareData();
    Log.d("ActivitiesFragment", "Data: \n\n" + activities);

    fabActivitiesAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(), AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
}

private void prepareData() {
    activities.clear();
    EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener = createList(ActivityModel.class, activities, 
        new FirestoreDateParser.FirestoreDataCallBack() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public <A extends FireStoreData> void getData(ArrayList<A> data) {
            mAdapter.setItems(data);
            if (activities.isEmpty())
                activities.addAll((ArrayList<? extends ActivityModel>) data);
            //for other fragments
            mAdapter.setItems(activities);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            Log.d("ActivitiesFragment", "Data: \n\n" + activities);
        }
    });
    //emphasis on the double 's'
    db.collection("activitiess")
            .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
}
}
```

The fragment above doesn't yield the result I wanted. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Do you see the content of the recycler view? Try to set the Refresh Layout android:layout_height to 0dp. Also, it is recommended to not use match_parent for views inside ConstraintLayout.

Comment: No. There's no feedback from Android Studio. The page is simply not refreshing when I drag it down. I don't see the refreshing icon. I also tried putting the content in the SwipeRefreshLayout in a ConstraintLayout. That didn't work either.